# Running Python Code

Tags: python, model, probability, markov

I'm completely new to Python and I am struggling to run a piece of code. I've put the code into IDLE and ran it but it returned nothing. Below I have attached the code and also the results that should accompany it. I am just wondering how you can get from the code to the results. Hopefully it is really easy.

The code in question refers to the probability of a Tennis player winning his service game at all possible scores (0-0,15-0,15-15 etc.) given his average percentage of service points won. This presumes that the game follows a markov process, i.e each point is independent of all other points

Here is the code:

https://gist.github.com/JeffSackmann/768862

Here is where I'd like to get to (Results):

https://summerofjeff.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/single-game-win-expectancy-tables/

Perhaps the problem isn't in the code but in the variables. If anyone could help me out, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you defined a bunch of functions, but you never actually called any of them. So the script will immediately exit.